# Regex removing extension and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm close to becoming a level 3 Regex Sorcerer (where I can find hidden traps and have a pet owl or bat), but I still need some help getting there...

The following works for the first two cases but fails for the third. I tried making the digits greedy but the whole thing fell over and I don't know where I'm going wrong.
Can you please help?

```
alert(removeNumberAndExtension("file 01.txt")) // works
alert(removeNumberAndExtension("file_01.txt")) // works
alert(removeNumberAndExtension("file.txt"))    // fails

function removeNumberAndExtension(fname)
{
  var rexp = new RegExp(/\s*\d+\.[a-zA-Z]+/g)
  return fname.replace(rexp, "")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `\d+`: *"**one** or more digits"*.

You need `\d*`: *"**zero** or more digits"*.

Files extensions can also have digits (e.g. *".mp3"*), so use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

You should add the *"end of the string"* anchor (`$`), which makes the *global flag* (`g`) useless.

All these together: `/\s*\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` :)

Comment: @GhoulFool: stick your expressions into www.regex101.com and have them explained, you're less likely to miss stuff like this then.

Comment: I was unaware of regex101.com; I'll take a butcher's!